# Interrogative implicit within a sentence

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, grammar, word-usage, syntactic-analysis

What is the grammatical term for sentences like:

1. Do you know **where he lives**?"
2. I can’t imagine **how he did it**."

In those sentences we use what is essentially an interrogative sentence (bolded), but we do not use inversion. We can't say, "Do you know **where does he live**?"

Now I want to know the correct way of referring to such constructions. I read somewhere  "double interrogative sentence" or similar, but I'm not sure.

Comment: "Embedded question".  (And "how" and "where" are *not* relative pronouns.)

Comment: [EstrellaMountain](http://www2.estrellamountain.edu/faculty/stonebrink/ESL040/121embeddques.pdf) give a nice explanation.

Answer (score 3):

In ***Do you know where he lives?***, the interrogative part is *do you know ?*.

I do not think *where he lives* is interrogative.

*Where* is simply acting as a relative pronoun, not an interrogative one, as in *That is the house where he lives*.

As regards ***I can't imagine how he did it*** there is no interrogation at all. It is not even a question, simply a statement of fact.

Comment: "You'll wonder where the yellow went" = "You'll wonder: 'Where did the yellow go?'"

Comment: I didnt ask for this... see the correct answer above,  Thnx by the way